# Dynamic Property Assignment Throws RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am getting a `RuntimeBinderException` with the message

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'MyNamespace.SomeEnum?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The following code generates that error:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    Val1
}

public class Example
{
    public SomeEnum? EnumMember { get; set; }
}

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic example = new Example();

        // Works without issue
        example.EnumMember = (dynamic)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), "Val1");

        // Works without issue
        example.EnumMember = Enum.Parse(example.EnumMember.GetType(), "Val1");

        // Throws the aforementioned RuntimeBinderException
        example.EnumMember = Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), "Val1");
    }
}
```

Why do to first two lines work (both return type dynamic), but the third throws an exception (when the return type is object)?  I was under the impression that, when assigning to dynamic, the binding is performed using the actual, run-time type of the right-hand-side.  Can someone please enlighten me as to why the third line is unable to run as written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compile-time type of the expression on the RHS of the `=` operator for the first two lines is `dynamic`. In the first case that's because you've cast to `dynamic`, and in the second case it's because you're using a dynamic value in one of the arguments.

In the third case, the compile-time type of the expression is `object`. So you're trying to do the equivalent of:

```
object x = Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), "Val1");
example.EnumMember = x;
```

That doesn't work, because there's no *implicit* conversion from `object` to `SomeEnum?`, which is what the compiler is trying to find at execution time.

Note that the nullability part really isn't relevant here - nor is the fact that it's an enum. It's just that the assignment operator is being bound dynamically, but using the compile-time time of the RHS. Here's a similar but simpler example:

```
class Test
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic example = new Test();

        example.Foo = 10; // Fine

        object o = 10;
        example.Foo = o; // Bang
    }
}
```

If you want the compiler to handle the assignment dynamically using the *actual* type of the value returned rather than the compile-time type, then using `dynamic` is exactly what you want to do - either cast to dynamic, or use:

```
dynamic value = ...;
target.SomeProperty = value;
```

Comment: Isn't the compile-time type of the RHS in the second example `object`, not `dynamic`?  That's where I was stuck - the second and third calls seem the same other than the compile-time resolution of `typeof`.

Comment: @DStanley: Nope, because the call is dynamically bound, because the first argument uses `example`. Try assigning the result to `var` instead and hover over the declaration and you'll see :)

Comment: @DStanley No, because example.EnumMember.GetType() returns `dynamic`, so the Enum.Parse expression must, by definition, also return type `dynamic`.

Comment: Ahh.  That's the difference.  Got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to do an implicit conversion for the third line

```
example.EnumMember = (SomeEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), "Val1");
```

**EDIT**

The reason that you still need implicit conversion is because `Enum.Parse` returns an object. Refer to the documentation below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OP knows that and is asking "why?"

Comment: The problem is that in real code, I don't know the type `SomeEnum`, so I can't explicitly add that cast.  If you know of some other way, without casting to `dynamic` or `SomeEnum` to get the assignment to work, I would love to learn it.